# How can I add a default og:image if image missing?

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags, yoast, share-open-graph

Is it possible to add a default image in open graph.
 `<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/example.jpg" />`
currently image is missing in category, pagination pages,archive pages etc. So I would like to add a default image in open graph. I am using Yoast SEO Wp plugin.